# Sqoop: How to export table from hive union resulting

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, sqoop

My use case is that I try to merge two tables in hive (external table) using `union all`, but the problem is that this union generates two directories (SUB_DIR_1 and SUB_DIR_2) instead files (SUCCES_, 0000, 0001), it complicates the **Sqoop export** using (export-dir).

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test(id INT, name STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION /user/foo/test;

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE test SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM test-1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM test-2
);
```

**Test-1**

```
 id    name
 1     coco
 2     bango
```

**Test-2**

```
 id    name
 3     goo
 4     boo
```

**Test**

```
 id     name
 1     coco
 2     bango
 3     goo
 4     boo
```

**Sqoop command:**

```
 sqoop export –connect jdbc:mysql://db.example.com/foo --table test --export-dir /user/foo/test
```

When I execute the Sqoop command I have the error:

> /user/foo/test.SUB_DIR_1 is not file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As possible workaround you can trigger reducer step when loading table by adding `DISTRIBUTE BY`:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE test 
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
  SELECT * FROM test-1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM test-2
) 
DISTRIBUTE BY ID;
```

This will load into table location without sub-directories.